How do I split a continuous texture into strips and offset each strip using the shader editor?
I have a homogeneous wooden texture applied to a plane. I want to split the texture into strips on one axis and then offset the uv of each strip to give the appearance of individual planks glued together and not one continuous texture. I know I can do this by loop cutting the mesh and the selecting each piece and manually offsetting the uv, but I'm trying to figure out a way to do this just from the shader editor so that I have quick control over the size of the strips (and also my mesh is not really a plane, it's more complicated, so doing the above mentioned way won't work).
I tried doing this by using a Separate XYZ node, then connecting a floored modulo math node to the x axis and decreasing the value, and then recombining the xyz.This does give me the strips I need. However, I cannot figure out how to offset the texture for each strip.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Extra question - is it possible to extract the border of each strip so that I can plug it into the normal map to give a slight indentaion where the "planks" would be glued together?

This is an example of alternated tiles, the pattern you want may be this or another, and you gotta figure out the math for that.

Key concepts:

Floored modulo and compares (top branch), if the floored modulo is near zero, it's a division between tiles, we use this as a factor to use a gap shader
Snap (middle branches): this creates discrete values (it's like the result of the division from the floored modulo instead of the remainder). Having discrete and "non varying" values is important so we can get a constant noise value for each tile (this noise will be used as a displacement on the texture map - hence the random multiplications by 40 and 70)
Some math using the integer result of dividing by X width, if odd, displace Y by length / 2 - this alternates tiles (and here is where you make different patterns if you want, like making a floored modulo by 3 and using 1/3 length, for instance).

File

Extra question - Create little normal angles on the planks
Using the same "snap" principle, but having a rotation of a gradient texture for serving as normal.
How to create procedural ceiling tile Gradient texture?
I guess you could increase the random multiplier in the extra question (needed that in the latest tests)

Thank you so much man, I gotta say I don't understand how this works at all with the math but with some playing around I was able to tweak it so I got the effect I was looking for. Cheers!
